# OpenAPI Swagger reusable schema parts

Tags: typescript, swagger, nestjs, swagger-ui, nestjs-swagger

I'm having some challenges while creating the swagger reusable schema components.

I have a lot of APIs in the project and most of them have the same headers and common error responses, of course, every API has its different response schema, to overcome this challenge I have created a decorator as bellow:

swagger-essentials.decorator.ts

```
type apiOkResponse = Type<unknown>;

export const SwaggerEssentials = (okRes?: apiOkResponse) => {
  return applyDecorators(
    SwaggerApiHeaders(),
    ApiResponse({ type: okRes, status: 200 }),
    HttpCode(200),
    ApiResponse({ type: ConnectTimeoutDTO, status: 599 }),
    ApiResponse({ type: JsonValidationErrorDTO, status: 501 }),
    SwaggerCommonResponses(),
  );
};
```

response.dto.ts

```
class Response {
  @ApiProperty()
  id: number;

  @ApiProperty()
  name:string;
}

export class RESPONSE_SCHEMA {
  @ApiProperty({ example: 'Success' })
  message: string;

  @ApiProperty({example: {}})
  data: Response;
}
```

And then in my controller, I use it like below:

xyz.controller.ts

```
@Post('/test')
@SwaggerEssentials(RESPONSE_SCHEMA)
fetchDetails(){}
```

Till here everything is fine and no problem, but as every API has its different response, however, there are two properties that remain the same in case of a successful response which are `message` and `data` of course the data will be different.

So, I want to have something through which I can get rid of above mentioned two properties and they are automatically defined/attached to the actual response.

I have tried `PartialType()` but it's not worthy to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be something that I too faced. But there are some downside of the code. `RESPONSE_SCHEMA` which should have been generic to accumulate any type of `data` is tightly bound to `Response` class. This can be fixed with the help of generics:

```
export class RESPONSE_SCHEMA <T = any>{
   data: T;
   message : string;
   headers?: Record<string, string>;
}
```

Now your controller function instead will return this:

```
@Post('/test')
@SwaggerEssentials(RESPONSE_SCHEMA)
fetchDetails():RESPONSE_SCHEMA<Response>{}
```

By this, you can get the desired response object in your swagger.

Also, you can remove the function parameter in `SwaggerEssentials` and try. It should work. Also, please recheck `SwaggerApiHeaders()` and `SwaggerCommonResponses()`. These don't seem to be classes in swagger module.

Comment: Hi, @Aditya Gaddhyan thanks for your answer unfortunately it's not what I was looking for as your answer only specifies the return type of `fetchDetails` using generic but I want it for Swagger.